# How to read only a few lines of data in Lookup activity in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read second row of my csv using Azure data factory Lookup activity. I will make a post request with that row as body using web activity, But if a file is large then i am getting a exception since lookup activity cannot load more data, is there a way to read specific number of lines in LookUp Activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to read specific number of lines in LookUp Activity?

Based on my [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#type-properties), there is no such property for you to read specific number of lines in Lookup Activity.

So,maybe lookup activity is not a suitable option. I suggest you that create an [Azure Function Http Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) to process your CSV file as you want with the C# package(or other language) and output the specific data. Then execute the Azure function in Azure data factory web activity and get the output data. Finally, go along with your custom subsequent activity.

Comment: It certainly adds a way to achieve what i wanted but i wanted a to know if it was possible to directly do it in lookup activity